# Testing object instance returns "Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, object-reference

I am trying to test for an instance of an object, but VB pukes and throws the exception:

```
Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.
```

Here is how I am testing:

```
Dim objGA As New Gatherer.Gathered("", -1)
objGA = objGatherers(idx) 
If Not objGA Is Nothing Then  <--exception occurs here
   ' Do something here

End If
```

If I do not do this check then I get:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I don't understand the first error given the `objGA` is an object not a string!

How else should I perform this test?  Is there a consistent way to check?

Comment: Could you paste objGatherers method code?. The error is inside it.

Comment: I cannot because I don't have access to the source.

Comment: What is the return type of Gatherer.Gathered("", -1) and objGatherers(idx)

Comment: You don't appear to have posted the code where the error occurs. Please indicate the line that gives the conversion error in your question.

Comment: @MattWilko   I have updated my post to reflect which line the exception occurs.

Comment: @CarlosLanderas  The returned object s/b a Gathered object.  Which is what the objGatherers is an array of.

Comment: @AndroidAddict - what is objGatherers?  List, array, etc?  Show how it is populated.

Answer (score 2):

```
If objGA IsNot Nothing Then
    ' put some code here...
End If
```

[MSDN: IsNot Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx)

Comment: Some explanation would be useful to future visitors.

Comment: This does not work - still get `Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.`

Comment: I don't think fundamentally there is a difference between the syntactically differing implementations of `Not object Is Nothing` and `object IsNot Nothing`.  They end up with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

try to check null object using `IsDBNull(oValue)` Method.
`IsDBNull` is inbuilt function to check null value.

```
Dim oValue As Object
Dim DefaultValue As Object
    If IsDBNull(oValue) Then
        Return DefaultValue
    Else
        Return oValue
    End If
```

Comment: IsDBNull is specifically for checking Null values returned from a database. It should not be used to check for Null References to Objects.

Comment: Check this link to know more about IsDBNull. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, my point entirely - have you read it? Specifically the definition of `DBNull`. This is what the `IsDBNull` method is doing doing a comparison on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.90).aspx *"The DBNull class represents a nonexistent value. In a database, for example, a column in a row of a table might not contain any data whatsoever."*

Comment: yes, i read it and  It does not be used to check for Null References to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim objGA As New Gatherer.Gathered("", -1)
    Stop 'examine objGA
    objGA = objGatherers(idx)
    Stop 'examine objGA
```

At the first stop is objGA a "Gathered object"?  When you type the first line does it tell you what the return type is?

Comment: `Stop 'examine objGA` - What have I not explained in my post about testing that?  Really, I would like to know where it's not clear so that refine my post and can get to an answer.  Not trying to be snarky.

Comment: @AndroidAddict - when you said, " The returned object s/b a Gathered object." it sounded like you didn't know.  If you put the check where the first Stop is you shouldn't get the error because it is a new instance of "Gathered object".

Comment: I do know and that's what it should be - no question in my mind.  Curious you read uncertainty in the statement - other than it's throwing the absurd exception.

Comment: @AndroidAddict - should be?  If you examine it at the stop there should be no question, it is or is not a Gathered object.  I also do not understand why you are using a method to create a Gathered object.

Comment: The `should be` comes from the thrown exception.  This should not be happening.  If it's not an object the test should fail and business as usual.  What's curious is the exception that's thrown.  That's the root of the `should be`.  The object gets created from a method because that's the way the author decided it should be and beyond the scope of the post.

Comment: @AndroidAddict - for testing put the If is nothing check after the Dim objGA and before the objGA ='s.  Do you get the error?

Comment: I do not.  The object returned is an empty object, but an object of the specific type nonetheless.